# Augmented Reality CoordinateFinding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

Hi friends how can i get the coordinate(latitude, longitude ) which is state 10 km far away from my location.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Googles geocoding service to lookup the lat/long for the known address or location for which you need the location.